# Cant find SDL.h - Windows, MingW, Cmake and SLD2 (in VSCode with CPP)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I want to add SDL2 to a Cmake Project, using C++ in VSCode on Windows, but using Mingw64 from Msys2 (g++).

This is my current CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TileGameStudio_Runtime LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(PROJ_SRC
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2/include)

file(GLOB PROJECT_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    ${PROJ_SRC}/*.cpp
)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\\Game")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\\Game")

# add the executable
add_executable(TileGameStudio_Runtime
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(TileGameStudio_Runtime PRIVATE
    SDL2-static
    SDL2main
)

set_target_properties(
    TileGameStudio_Runtime
    PROPERTIES
        OUTPUT_NAME "Game"
        SUFFIX ".exe"
)
```

[This is my current Project Structure (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j51Rj.png)

As you can see. i cloned the Repo from https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL as a subdirectory to my Project. And this, i added via cmake add_subdirectory.

My Main.cpp is simply this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>

#ifdef main
# undef main
#endif /* main */

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Window *win = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    int posX = 100, posY = 100, width = 320, height = 240;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", posX, posY, width, height, 0);

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    //================================================ Draw a Text
    //this opens a font style and sets a size
    TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Sans.ttf", 24);
    // this is the color in rgb format,
    // maxing out all would give you the color white,
    // and it will be your text's color
    SDL_Color White = {255, 255, 255};

    // as TTF_RenderText_Solid could only be used on
    // SDL_Surface then you have to create the surface first
    SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "put your text here", White); 
    SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);
    SDL_Rect Message_rect; //create a rect
    Message_rect.x = 0;  //controls the rect's x coordinate 
    Message_rect.y = 0; // controls the rect's y coordinte
    Message_rect.w = 100; // controls the width of the rect
    Message_rect.h = 100; // controls the height of the rect
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, NULL, &Message_rect);
    //================================================ Draw a Text End

    while (1) {
        SDL_Event e;
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                break;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Which should create a Window.. and perhaps draw a text to it.
But, SDL.h can´t be found... so i can´t build the Stuff here..

Comment: Did you install the SDL package in MSYS2? Which MSYS2 mode are you running? (What does it say in magenta in the terminal prompt, `MINGW64` or `MSYS` or something else?)

Comment: SDL2 is not loaded via msys or anything else. the Repo (linked in original post) is directly cloned into the project folder and linked via add_subdirectories and target_link_libraries of cmake.  Msys2 is used to get mingw64 and the gcc Compiler. The errors in the terminal are occurring cause SDL.h can't be found.. this gives many more Errors, based on the origin of SDL.h

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't notice. Is there a reason you don't want to use a prebuilt one? You need to install a bunch of dependencies to build it properly... (This is not what causes your problem, but without the dependencies the resulting build might be inferior compared to the official one.)

Comment: The msys and tarball version weren't found either.. + problems with the make commands to build the tarball version.. That's the reason I want to try the Repo version.

Comment: If both aren't working, go back to MSYS2 package. Please tell me what exact package you installed, and what MSYS2 mode are you running (see my first comment for how to determine mode).

Comment: Msys2 is in MSYS Mode

Comment: That isn't the mode you need. You need `MINGW64`. Restart MSYS2 using `mingw64.exe`. Install those packages: `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-sdl2`, etc. Remove plain `gcc`, `sdl2`, and whatever you installed.

Comment: See my new Answer pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my CMakeLists.txt, cause i reinstalled the whole msys2 (since of a installation problem).
This is the new One:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TileGameStudio_Runtime LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -v)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(PROJ_SRC
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)

file(GLOB PROJECT_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    ${PROJ_SRC}/*.cpp
)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\\Game")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\\Game")

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_MIXER REQUIRED SDL2_mixer)

include_directories(
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories (
    ${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

# add the executable
add_executable(TileGameStudio_Runtime
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries (TileGameStudio_Runtime 
    ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARIES}
)

set_target_properties(
    TileGameStudio_Runtime
    PROPERTIES
        OUTPUT_NAME "Game"
        SUFFIX ".exe"
)
```

I installed the whole mingw64 toolchain and SDL2 via msys (under MingW64 Mode of msys2) now.

it still couldn´t find the SDL.h or SDL2/SDL.h

I checked the SDL2_Dir in the Cmake GUI.. and it has the correct Path to: "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/cmake/SDL2"

EDIT:
I now changed the Main Folder of all my Projects (unreal, unity..etc) from "Game Design" to "Game_Design"..  Working like a Charm now...   Cause.. Spaces are evil..  very evil...
Thanks for your Help Trys :D   <3